PySide6 module is not installed when importing addon modules
This is a bit too simple to be QA, but still may be worth posting.
Basically multiple additional Qt  modules like QtPositioning, QtLocation, QtMultimedia, when imported from qml files give module * is not installed 
Error does not happen when trying to run default projects in Qt Creator or Design Studio, but heppens when trying to run from bare PySide6.

Specific case I had is that for PySide6 this error can also be provoked by installation via conda.
Somehow pip adds PySide6-Addons automatically while conda does not.
